# How to call https url from angular 6

Tags: angular

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' })
};

return this.http.get<any>('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=1600+Amphitheatre+Pa 
 rkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=myapikey',
       httpOptions);
```

When i run this url i am getting below error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAFZSWxtOreMcERHby_vD4x_XgVWfamweY' from origin 
'http://192.168.4.52:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Request header field access-control-allow-headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: It's a cors origin issue, you should add proper cofig in your google maps api.